# How to turn a grouped df with hierarchical index back to a df with multi level index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

My Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["2012-01-06",1,"a",2],["2012-01-06",1,"b",3],["2012-01-06",1,"b",4],["2012-01-06",1,"b",5],["2012-02-06",2,"a",3],["2012-02-06",2,"a",4],["2012-02-06",3,"b",3],["2012-03-06",5,"b",3]],columns=["date","id","type", "amount"])
df = df.set_index(["date","id","type"])
df
```

results in:

```
                    amount
date       id type        
2012-01-06 1  a          2
              b          3
              b          4
              b          5
2012-02-06 2  a          3
              a          4
           3  b          3
2012-03-06 5  b          3
```

After I perform grouping

```
gr = df.groupby(df.index).agg({'amount':sum})
gr
```

I get:

```
                    amount
(2012-01-06, 1, a)       2
(2012-01-06, 1, b)      12
(2012-02-06, 2, a)       7
(2012-02-06, 3, b)       3
(2012-03-06, 5, b)       3
```

What do I need to turn `gr` into the same structure as my original `df`, i.e.

```
                    amount
date       id type        
2012-01-06 1  a          2
              b         12
2012-02-06 2  a          7
           3  b          3
2012-03-06 5  b          3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group using the dataframe's levels instead:

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1,2]).amount.sum()

    date        id  type
2012-01-06  1   a        2
                b       12
2012-02-06  2   a        7
            3   b        3
2012-03-06  5   b        3
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) with `level` parameter what working same like `groupby` with `level` parameter:

```
s = df.amount.sum(level=[0,1,2])
print (s)
date        id  type
2012-01-06  1   a        2
                b       12
2012-02-06  2   a        7
            3   b        3
2012-03-06  5   b        3
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```